# Aspect isn't called

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

I am trying to call aspect after method execution. But is doesn't even go to code inside aspect.

Here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:auditorium.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.epam.spring.hometask.*" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {
      ///Bean definitions
}
```

This is my aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class CounterAspect {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.epam.spring.hometask.service.EventService.getByName(..))", returning = "event")
    public void calculateAccessEventByNameCounter(Event event) {
        System.out.println("Aspect running");       
    }
```

This is function signature I want to provide with my aspect:

```
public Event getByName(String name);
```

And test:

```
@Test
    public void getByNameTest(){
        Event actualEvent = eventService.getByName("Test event 1");
    }
```

Nothing is printed after getByName call

Comment: Is your aspect in the package that you are scanning? How is your test loading the configuration and/or how are you obtaining the `EventService`. Does that class implement an interface? If not add `proxy-target-class=true` to the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation.

Comment: Try `execution(* com.epam.spring.hometask.service.EventService+.getByName(..))` notice the additional `+`.

Comment: @InjectMocks
    private EventService eventService = PowerMockito.spy(new EventServiceImpl()); - this is how I use eventService

Comment: Which explains why it isn't working. You are creating a mock and expect Spring AOP to proxy it. How is that even going to happen to a non spring bean. Spring AOP will only work on spring beans not on regularly instantiated classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Event event = new Event();
event.getByName();
```

Event should be a spring-managed bean for the aspects to be applied, i.e. you should obtain objects of type Event from the ApplicationContext as follows:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/Spring.xml");
Event event = context.getBean(Event.class);
```

or get them injected using @Resource or @Autowired annotations.

Then, the call to getByName() on event object will go through the AOP proxy created by Spring framework and the code in the AOP advices that match the method definition get executed.

Another way to get a spring-managed bean, while creating objects using new operator, is using the @Configurable annotation.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I understood something wrong. But I call method on eventService object. And this is a component: @Component
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService. And I autowire this bean into test class

Comment: Yes sorry, it should be EventService ... sorry for the typo.